"manage.py runserver" now does not run with "py", only "python" overnight
Beginning with web development, using VSCode, Python 3.12.3 in a virtual environment, and Django 5.0.6.
When running:
py manage.py runserver

I get:
Unable to create process using 'c:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\GitHub\Coding Practice\Python\DjangoLearningMongo\.venv\Scripts\python.exe manage.py runserver'

Another post suggested using just manage.py runserver, but that yields:
Unable to create process using 'c:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\GitHub\Coding Practice\Python\DjangoLearningMongo\.venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\GitHub\Coding Practice\Python\DjangoLearningMongo\grocery_prices_mongo\manage.py"  runserver'

I have used py manage.py runserver for the entirety of the project just fine until this morning. Now, py fails to work with anything, yielding the above, and instead I must use python.
These are the changes I made to the project yesterday:

added static files to the project (static folder, settings.py to have STATIC_ROOT, py manage.py collectstatic, etc...)
pip installed whitenoise to handle static CSS in production
set DEBUG to FALSE
Added 127.0.0.1 to ALLOWED_HOSTS

I was still able to use py manage.py runserver (or other py manage.py commands) each step of the way as I made these changes, it was only this morning when I returned to the project that py stopped working and had to use python instead, which I had not needed to do at any point prior in the project.
I even went to another project I have not run or edited in a week or so and it gets the same error when using py, even though its venv is on a different version of Python than the project I first encountered the error with.
When I made a brand new Django project, it worked using py, both within and outside of a virtual environment.
I have tried:

deactivating and reactivating the virtual environment
upgrading pip
removing and remaking the virtual environment
repairing the Python installation the venv used when creating the venv
removing and remaking the virtual environment again after repairing the installation
restoring the project to a version from before the recent changes

Each step would yield the same result for the project -- py failed to work with the same error, while python would work.
In the process, I did find that py and python point to different Python versions when used outside of a virtual environment (3.12.3 and 3.10.4, respectively). However, despite this, py would get the same error on both the 3.12.3 venv project and the 3.10.4 venv project, while python would work for both.
I checked my PATH environmental variables, and they are unchanged.
What could have induced this change, and how can I get the original functionality for py back?
Edit:

Just py raises the same error inside the venv, and works as expected outside the venv (but cannot run the server due to installed package differences between global and the venv)
Accessing the project through the terminal instead of VSCode and activating the virtual environment yields the same error when using py


what happens when you just execute py? both outside and inside your venv

Try to access your project from your terminal (instead of vscode). Activate your venv and run py manage.py runserver. What do you get?

From your drive letter format c:, I assume you are working with Windows OS.
It seems the symbolic link between py and python.exe is broken on your machine. Anything can cause that so let’s not delve into details.
To fix the broken link, you can simply recreate it using mklink [microsoft.com] command on Windows OS.
mklink opt <link> <target>
In your case I will use:
mklink /h \path\to\py \path\to\python.exe
Notice the use of hard link instead of soft link? That way it refers to the same inode as the original file.

Would the path to python.exe be to the python.exe for the virtual environment, in this case, in \.venv\Scripts\.python.exe and \path\to\py to the project root directory? py manage.py runserver works in newly made projects and functions outside the virtual environment, so it is not broken over the entire machine, just for past Django projects.

1. No. The python.exe of the virtual environment is a soft link to the main interpreter on the platform on Windows OS. Of course this is if you didn’t use the --copies option for venv. 2. The py command works for new projects because when creating a new virtual environment, venv creates a soft link to the main Python interpreter. In your case it creates both soft link python.exe and py in the virtual environment. But previous soft links to the main interpreter were broken for some reason. This is why soft links in old projects and the soft link py no longer work.
